# How to set List value to a entity field

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

```
public List<DetailsField> getDetails(String id){
List<Response> res = detailsService.getApiDetails(id);//I am getting details from API
System.out.println(res); //here res is coming
DetailsField detail = new DetailsField();
for(Response response: res){
System.out.println(response); //here response is coming
detail.setValue(List<Response> response);
}
return (List<DetailsField> )detail);
}
```

Basically I am getting the details from res but I need to set res details to value field of DetailsField class.

```
public class DetailsField
{
 private String idS;
 private List<Response> value;
}
```

But I get an 500 internal error and when I check the logs, I see that Response cannot be casted to list. I am not sure of as res -> I am getting the values and response -> I am getting the values, I feel issue is while setting up the res values to DetailsField class field value.

Comment: `private String List<Response> value;` You're declaring `value` as a list and as a string, this is strange...

Comment: your code does not compile!

Comment: Yes, it compiles but it gives 500 internal error on postman

Comment: private String List<Response> value sorry typo error it is -> private List<Response> value;

Answer (score 0):

*If I understood it correctly you are trying to return the `DetailsField` object after setting the `List<Response> res` which you are getting from the API so it seems you can have the `DetailsField` object as the return type instead of `List<DetailsField> list`*

**Note:**

1. Replace the `Response.java` class with your required implementation.
2. Replace the hardcoded list `res` with your actual API response.

***You can try this approach:***

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getDetails("1"));
    }

    public static DetailsField getDetails(String id){
        List<Response> res = Arrays.asList(new Response("response1"),new Response("response2"));
        // I have hardcoded it for the demo
        System.out.println(res); //here res is coming
        DetailsField detail = new DetailsField();
        detail.setIdS(id);
        detail.setValue(res);
        return detail;
    }
}
```

**Response.java**

```
public class Response {

    private String output;

    public Response(String output) {
        this.output = output;
    }

    public String getOutput() {
        return output;
    }

    public void setOutput(String output) {
        this.output = output;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Response{" +
                "output='" + output + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**DetailsField.java**

```
public class DetailsField {

    private String idS;
    private List<Response> value;

    public DetailsField(){}

    public DetailsField(String idS, List<Response> value) {
        this.idS = idS;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getIdS() {
        return idS;
    }

    public void setIdS(String idS) {
        this.idS = idS;
    }

    public List<Response> getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(List<Response> value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DetailsField{" +
                "idS='" + idS + '\'' +
                ", value=" + value +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[Response{output='response1'}, Response{output='response2'}]
DetailsField{idS='1', value=[Response{output='response1'}, Response{output='response2'}]}
```